# T-SQL XML to Table performance issues

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm new to xml and try to transform about 200 XML files, totalling about 60GB, to a table. This works, but runs for nearly 7 days.

Maybe one of you could give me some hints on how to tune this query.

Anyway, here's the data:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = 
    '<DB>
        <BN>61</BN>
        
        <DA>
            <PN>1</PN>
            <SN>94</SN>
            <A>2015</A>
            <B>2020</B>
            <T M="1">91</T>
            <T M="3">92</T>
            <T M="7">93</T>
            <TBS V="+">22</TBS>
            <TBS V="+">24</TBS>
            <AK>
                <P>11</P>
                <PL>V</PL>
                <BI>103</BI>
            </AK>
            <GB>
                <GT>S</GT>
                <VZ>+</VZ>
                <OG>
                    <OI>S</OI>
                    <VA>U</VA>
                    <E>
                        <EI>32</EI>
                        <PN>1</PN>
                        <VZ>+</VZ>
                    </E>
                </OG>
            </GB>
        </DA>
        <DA>
            <PN>1</PN>
            <SN>5A</SN>
            <A>2015</A>
            <B>2022</B>
            <T M="4">51</T>
            <T M="2">52</T>
            <T M="9">12</T>
        </DA>
        <DA>
            <PN>1</PN>
            <SN>58</SN>
            <A>2016</A>
            <T M="14">91</T>
            <T M="12">92</T>
            <T M="11">11</T>
        </DA>
        <DA>
            <PN>1</PN>
            <SN>74</SN>
            <A>2010</A>
            <B>2018</B>
            <T M="51">51</T>
            <T M="11">52</T>
            <T M="11">33</T>
            <NI>
                <NS>747</NS>
                <T M="32">11</T>
                <T M="33">12</T>
                <T M="35">13</T>
            </NI>
        </DA>
    </DB>';
```

and this is the query I'm using

```
SELECT 
        XX.YY.value('(BN)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS BN,
        H.HH.value('(PN)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS DA_PN,
        H.HH.value('(SN)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS DA_NR,
        H.HH.value('(A)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS DA_A,
        H.HH.value('(B)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS DA_B,
        I.II.value('@M', 'nvarchar(10)') AS DA_M,
        I.II.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS DA_T,
        J.JJ.value('@V', 'nvarchar(10)') AS TBS_V,
        J.JJ.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS TBS,
        K.KK.value('(NS)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS NI_NS,
        L.LL.value('@M', 'nvarchar(10)') AS NI_M,
        L.LL.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS NI_T,
        M.MM.value('(P)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS AK_P,
        M.MM.value('(PL)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS AK_PL,
        M.MM.value('(BI)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS AK_BI,
        N.NN.value('(GT)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS GB_GT,
        N.NN.value('(VZ)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS GB_VZ,
        O.OO.value('(OI)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS OG_OI,
        O.OO.value('(VA)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS OG_VA,
        P.PP.value('(EI)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS OG_EI,
        P.PP.value('(PN)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS OG_PN,
        P.PP.value('(VZ)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS E_VZ
FROM @xml.nodes('/DB') AS XX(YY)
OUTER APPLY XX.YY.nodes('DA') AS H(HH)
OUTER APPLY H.HH.nodes('T') AS I(II)
OUTER APPLY H.HH.nodes('TBS') AS J(JJ)
OUTER APPLY H.HH.nodes('NI') AS K(KK)
OUTER APPLY K.KK.nodes('T') AS L(LL)
OUTER APPLY H.HH.nodes('AK') AS M(MM)
OUTER APPLY H.HH.nodes('GB') AS N(NN)
OUTER APPLY N.NN.nodes('OG') AS O(OO)
OUTER APPLY O.OO.nodes('E') AS P(PP);
```

I think, that the main issue are those 9 `outer apply`. But I cannot find a better way to make this work.

Thank you :)

Comment: There's no data type that would be able to hold that value in SQL Server; the largest data size a column can be is 2GB; it has no way of consuming a single XML file that is 60GB is size.

Comment: sorry, my fault! those were 210 files, in total ~60GB... I've put them in one table...

Comment: Why are you using `nvarchar100` when most looks to be integers or single characters - are you sure you absolutely need unicode?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it's all ints... so that's why I'm using nvarchar(100)... After my analysis I'll change the columns to it's correct data type

Comment: The correct data type usage has an impact on performance, not just on storage; for string data types, SQL Server has to estimate the amount of memory a query will be allocated prior to its execution, it has no idea what data it will actually find, it makes a guess based on the data types, which can mean you are reserving far too much or little memory depending.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that duplicate nodes in one level means that you will get a very large denormalized table, when perhaps you can normalize it better. For example, could `DA_T` and `NI_T` be combined?

You don't need `.nodes` to pull out a single value, you only need it if you want to shred child nodes into rows.

So if there are any nodes for which you are sure you only get one of, or you where you know how many and would anyway like to pivot up, you can remove that `.nodes` and instead use just `.value` on its parent.

---

You should choose the right data type, here it looks like most of them should be `int`. Also, `text()` is faster than `.`, so your code will become this

```sql
SELECT 
        XX.YY.value('(BN/text())[1]', 'int') AS BN,
        H.HH.value('(PN/text())[1]', 'int') AS DA_PN,
        H.HH.value('(SN/text())[1]', 'int') AS DA_NR,
        H.HH.value('(A/text())[1]', 'int') AS DA_A,
        H.HH.value('(B/text())[1]', 'int') AS DA_B,
        I.II.value('@M', 'nvarchar(10)') AS DA_M,
        I.II.value('text()[1]', 'int') AS DA_T,
        J.JJ.value('@V', 'nvarchar(10)') AS TBS_V,
        J.JJ.value('text()[1]', 'int') AS TBS,
        K.KK.value('(NS/text())[1]', 'int') AS NI_NS,
        L.LL.value('@M', 'nvarchar(10)') AS NI_M,
        L.LL.value('text()[1]', 'int') AS NI_T,
        M.MM.value('(P/text())[1]', 'int') AS AK_P,
        M.MM.value('(PL/text())[1]', 'int') AS AK_PL,
        M.MM.value('(BI/text())[1]', 'int') AS AK_BI,
        N.NN.value('(GT/text())[1]', 'int') AS GB_GT,
        N.NN.value('(VZ/text())[1]', 'int') AS GB_VZ,
        O.OO.value('(OI/text())[1]', 'int') AS OG_OI,
        O.OO.value('(VA/text())[1]', 'int') AS OG_VA,
        P.PP.value('(EI/text())[1]', 'int') AS OG_EI,
        P.PP.value('(PN/text())[1]', 'int') AS OG_PN,
        P.PP.value('(VZ/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS E_VZ
FROM @xml.nodes('/DB') AS XX(YY)
OUTER APPLY XX.YY.nodes('DA') AS H(HH)
OUTER APPLY H.HH.nodes('T') AS I(II)
OUTER APPLY H.HH.nodes('TBS') AS J(JJ)
OUTER APPLY H.HH.nodes('NI') AS K(KK)
OUTER APPLY K.KK.nodes('T') AS L(LL)
OUTER APPLY H.HH.nodes('AK') AS M(MM)
OUTER APPLY H.HH.nodes('GB') AS N(NN)
OUTER APPLY N.NN.nodes('OG') AS O(OO)
OUTER APPLY O.OO.nodes('E') AS P(PP);
```

Comment: thank you for this one! unfortunatelly there are multiple children there, so that's why I'm using all those ´outer apply´... And your suggestion with `text()` is beatiful, thank you!